# Trouble passing basic function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a very basic function that takes the first six letters of a string. I want to apply it to a column in my DataFrame.

code:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfp = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,3,4,5,5,3,1,5,np.NaN], 
                    'B' : [1,0,3,5,0,0,np.NaN,9,0,0], 
                    'C' : ['AA1233445','A9875', 'rmacy','Idaho Rx','Ab123455','TV192837','RX','Ohio Drugs','RX12345','USA Pharma'], 
                    'D' : [123456,123456,1234567,12345678,12345,12345,12345678,123456789,1234567,np.NaN],
                    'E' : ['Assign','Unassign','Assign','Ugly','Appreciate','Undo','Assign','Unicycle','Assign','Unicorn',]})
def six_dig(thing):
    return str(thing)[:6]

dfp6= dfp[dfp['C'].apply(six_dig, axis=1)]
```

But i get: `TypeError: six_dig() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`
I even tried using `.map()` but get the same error.

If I remove `axis=1` I get: `KeyError: ["STUFF"] not in index`

I must be missing something super simple as I've used functions on DataFrame columns before...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can just:

```
dfp6 = dfp['C'].str[:6]
```

this returns:

```
In [14]: dfp6
Out[14]: 
0    AA1233
1     A9875
2     rmacy
3    Idaho 
4    Ab1234
5    TV1928
6        RX
7    Ohio D
8    RX1234
9    USA Ph
Name: C, dtype: object
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks for saving me that small step. @pansen 's answer also showed me what was wrong.

Comment: @MattR glad it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Using your example, the following works just fine:

```
print(dfp['C'].map(six_dig))
0    AA1233
1     A9875
2     rmacy
3    Idaho 
4    Ab1234
5    TV1928
6        RX
7    Ohio D
8    RX1234
9    USA Ph
Name: C, dtype: object
```

Comment: I knew it was something so simple.... I was adding an extra `dfp[]` around my example.... it took you typing this out to make me see it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use vectorized functions - here is an example:

```
In [35]: def my_slice(ser, start=0, end=10, step=1):
    ...:     return ser.str.slice(start, end, step)
    ...:

In [36]: my_slice(dfp.C, end=6)
Out[36]:
0    AA1233
1     A9875
2     rmacy
3    Idaho
4    Ab1234
5    TV1928
6        RX
7    Ohio D
8    RX1234
9    USA Ph
Name: C, dtype: object
```